# Windows Azure project not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I was following [Window Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx) tutorial for Eclipse. I downloaded the SDK and the ToolKit. On Item no 6, the tutorial asked me to create Windows Azure project, but I don’t see Windows Azure Project listed as an available project. I can see PHP Windows Azure Project. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Need download Window Azure Plugin for Eclipse for Java from http://webdownload.persistent.co.in/windowsazureplugin4ej/
Help -> Install New Software -> http://webdownload.persistent.co.in/windowsazureplugin4ej/